# If someone has shared a file with me on Dropbox, can I save it on my computer?

Tags: dropbox

If someone has shared a file with me on Dropbox, can I save it on my computer, so that I have a copy in case they decide to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, as long as you store it outside of the shared Dropbox. **DO NOT MOVE** the file, but *copy* the file.

If you *move* the file (simple drag & drop), the file will be removed from Dropbox on your machine *and* on the person who is sharing the file! In that case the person who shared the file will have LOST it!